# how to get pdf file to the temp storage file, from Url in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

```cs
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/FixesViaMail_17Dec.pdf", UriKind.Absolute);
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

This code is working very well because i m using my system file path but whenever i am using this code

```cs
var uri = new System.Uri("http://www.visa.com/assets/upload/11458/Hotel/Voucher114581423144270.pdf", UriKind.Absolute);
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

then i am getting error that is.....
Value does not fall within the expected range.

Please Help me

Answer (score 3):

GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync is only used for loading a file from within your application. To read a file from the web you'll need to download it. You can do this with either the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient) (for small files) or [BackgroundDownloader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx) (for large files) classes.

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://www.visa.com/assets/upload/11458/Hotel/Voucher114581423144270.pdf");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

// Always catch network exceptions for async methods
try 
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    // save response out
}
catch 
{
    // Details in ex.Message and ex.HResult.       
}
```

See [Connecting to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594) for more details.

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://www.visa.com/assets/upload/11458/Hotel/Voucher114581423144270.pdf");
BackgroundDownloader download = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, destinationFile);
```

See [Transferring data in the background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452979.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi Romasz thanks  but plz let me know how to get stream of that kind of file like in next code line i need.. using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
               {
                   Document doc = new Document(stream);
                   Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer.Page page = doc.Pages[0];
                   ErrorLogger logger = new ErrorLogger();
                   WriteableBitmap bm = page.Render((int)page.Width, (int)page.Height, new RenderingSettings(), logger);
                   myImage.Source = bm;
               } but i am getting error that--document load error